# How can obtain middle number with grid/step in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to know how obtain with python 2.7 the middle number in a range like but with a predefined grid per example of 40 per 40 (multiple of 40):

`0, 600` the number will be `320` and not 300 because 300 is not a multiple of 40...
`0, 300` the number will be `160` and not 150 because 150 is not a multiple of 40...

Any help will be appreciated...

EDIT
i want a function or something like that not myself calculating...

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Try implementing this yourself, and come back with a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: For `0, 600` why not 280 instead of 320?

Comment: @MattDMo can be 280 too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
def mean_mod(a, b, md=40):
    return md * ( ((a+b)//2) // md )

print(mean_mod(0, 600))
print(mean_mod(0, 300))
```

output:

```
280
120
```

(rounds down...)